# Make mat-icon fit container div

Tags: html, css, angular, material-design

I'm trying to make `mat-icon` fit their container, But I can't manage to do this on when use `%`.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-icons-dhktin

How can I make the icon large like the container?

Answer (score 0):

You can add your css

```
mat-icon{
  font-size:30px;
  transform: scale(12,1.2);
  transform-origin: left;
  margin-left:-20px;
}
```

[example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-icons-6fgaoy)

Comment: this resize the svg, but do not fit the container https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-icons-dhktin

Comment: thank you for your time, and sorry, but maybe I am not specific enough, what I mean on the first post is, when I edit my div, the svg always fit the container, so any resized size of the container wil make the svg fit

Answer (score 0):

On your scss or css file add:

```
mat-icon{
 font-size: #px;
}
```

Comment: this resize the svg, but do not fit the container https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-icons-dhktin

Answer (score 0):

Try this on your html

```html
    <div class="container" >
      <i class="material-icons">brush</i>
    </div>
```

and

add this to the css file

```css
   .container{
     width:50%;
     height:100%;
   }

   .material-icons{
     font-size: 200px;
     background-color:red;
   }
```

[Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-icons-xjeryz)

Comment: Updated css Code